# Activating a radio button without the use of another button

Tags: powershell, radio-button

This is probably a dumb question, but I just cannot seem to get this working and the research I have been doing has not been helpful. I can get this to work if I add a button and just adding a handler to that but I wanted to see if it was possible to have the radio activate automatically when it is activated. Whenever one of the radio buttons is clicked, it will activate without the need of another function.

Here is my full code to show what I have been trying to do.

```
$hddenfile = (Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced' 'Hidden')
$hidextensions = (Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced' 'HideFileExt') 


[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "File Options"
$Form.Name = "form1"
$Form.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 200
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 275
$Form.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 27
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 190
$Form.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$Form.WindowState = "Normal"
$Form.Opacity = 1.0
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"


$Label1                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.text                     = "Hidden Files and Folders"
$Label1.AutoSize                 = $true
$Label1.width                    = 25
$Label1.height                   = 10
$Label1.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(23,25)
$Label1.Font                     = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Groupbox1                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Groupbox
$Groupbox1.height                = 70
$Groupbox1.width                 = 116
$Groupbox1.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(18,54)

$RadioButton1                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$RadioButton1.Name               = 'Radio1'
$RadioButton1.text               = "Hide Files"
$RadioButton1.AutoSize           = $true
$RadioButton1.width              = 104
$RadioButton1.height             = 20
$RadioButton1.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(17,14)
$RadioButton1.Font               = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$RadioButton1.Checked            = if($hddenfile -eq 2){ $true } else{$false}       
$RadioButton1.add_Click($handler_RadioButton1_Click)

$RadioButton2                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$RadioButton2.Name               = 'Radio2'
$RadioButton2.text               = "Show Files"
$RadioButton2.AutoSize           = $true
$RadioButton2.width              = 104
$RadioButton2.height             = 20
$RadioButton2.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(17,46)
$RadioButton2.Font               = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$RadioButton2.Checked            = if($hddenfile -eq 1){ $true } else{$false}   
$RadioButton2.add_Click($handler_RadioButton2_Click)

$Groupbox2                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Groupbox
$Groupbox2.height                = 78
$Groupbox2.width                 = 150
$Groupbox2.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(18,161)

$RadioButton3                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$RadioButton3.text               = "Hide Extensions"
$RadioButton3.AutoSize           = $true
$RadioButton3.width              = 104
$RadioButton3.height             = 20
$RadioButton3.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,19)
$RadioButton3.Font               = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$RadioButton3.Checked            = if($hidextensions -eq 2){ $true } else{$false}       

$RadioButton4                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$RadioButton4.text               = "Show Extensions"
$RadioButton4.AutoSize           = $true
$RadioButton4.width              = 104
$RadioButton4.height             = 20
$RadioButton4.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,49)
$RadioButton4.Font               = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$RadioButton4.Checked            = if($hidextensions -eq 1){ $true } else{$false}       

$Label2                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label2.text                     = "Extensions for Known Files"
$Label2.AutoSize                 = $true
$Label2.width                    = 25
$Label2.height                   = 10
$Label2.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(23,137)
$Label2.Font                     = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Form.Controls.Add($Label1)
$Form.Controls.Add($Label2)
$Form.Controls.Add($Groupbox1)
$Form.Controls.Add($Groupbox2)
$Form.Controls.Add($RadioButton1)
$Form.Controls.Add($RadioButton2)
$Form.Controls.Add($RadioButton3)
$Form.Controls.Add($RadioButton4)

$RadioButton1.Check


$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Label1,$Groupbox1,$Groupbox2,$Label2))
$Groupbox1.controls.AddRange(@($RadioButton1,$RadioButton2))
$Groupbox2.controls.AddRange(@($RadioButton3,$RadioButton4))

$RadioButton1_CheckedChanged={
             if($RadioButton1.Checked -eq $true){
                   (Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced -Name Hidden -Value 2)}}

$RadioButton2_CheckedChanged={
             if($RadioButton2.Checked -eq $true){
                   (Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced -Name Hidden -Value 1)}}

$Form.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
$Form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null



Pause
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out pretty much 10 minutes after asking the question.

Here is the example of code I used for Button1:

```
$RadioButton1.add_Click({Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced -Name Hidden -Value 2})
```